# Cell biology books

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling

I'd like to know, what is the best list of books for non-biologist to understand, how signalling between organels is organized inside of eukaryotic cells. I really want to get how cell as separate system works until apoptosis happen.

Of course, any useful online courses (like MIT ocw) are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> **BOOKS**

If you want to learn about cells in detail from scratch to advanced level I recommend you two books:

1. **Molecular Biology of the Cell**, 6th Edition. 2014. Bruce Alberts, Alexander Johnson, Julian Lewis, David Morgan, Martin Raff, Keith
   Roberts, Peter Walter
   http://www.garlandscience.com/product/isbn/9780815344322
2. **Essential Cell Biology**, 4th Edition. 2013. Bruce Alberts, Dennis Bray, Karen Hopkin, Alexander D Johnson, Julian Lewis, Martin Raff,
   Keith Roberts, Peter Walter (*This can probably be considered the
   "light" version of the first book above*)
   http://www.garlandscience.com/product/isbn/9780815344544

Then if you really want to put everything you learn into practice and learn them in-depth, you can try the Problems Book of the first book mentioned above:

3. **Molecular Biology of the Cell 6E - The Problems Book**. John Wilson, Tim Hunt garlandscience.com/product/isbn/9780815344537

> **ONLINE COURSES**

1. Crash Course in Biology -- on YouTube
2. Introduction to Biology - The Secret of Life -- available on exd.org
   -- provided by MIT
3. Simply just search for "Biology" on coursera.org and you will find dozens of good courses

Finally, I highly encourage you to look into the first book I mentioned (Molecular Biology of the Cell, 6th Edition). It's a fantastic book and it will teach you much about biology and cells.